# Dot in .htaccess not working and weird redirect to server path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I  'm trying to get my .htaccess File work. But it seems to have a few problems:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^css/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^img/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^js/ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.ch$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.ch/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(dir1/dir2)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\_,]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(dir1/dir2)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\_,]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(dir1)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\_,]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\_,]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

1) In my .htaccess the dot doesn't work. When i write the last rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I just get the 'home' page. If I var_dump($_GET) there's the key 'page', as it should, but it's value is 'index.php'. How comes, it doesnt contain whats written in the address?

2) There was an older Version of this Website with URLs like www.example.ch/page.php. I want to redirect the old .php sites to the new Website, so visitors which click on an old link in google won't get an 404 error. When I type in example.ch/page.php, with the above .htaccess i get redirected to something like:

```
 http://example.ch/home/httpd/vhosts/example.ch/httpdocs/page
```

What's the reason for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question 1

This ones an easy fix... It's because your `.htaccess` file is rewriting the rewritten url. To illustrate:

```
http://mysite.com/this/content                     <---Original URL
http://mysite.com/index.php?key1=this&key2=content <---First rewrite
http://mysite.com/index.php?key1=index.php         <---Second rewrite/final url
```

To fix this you can simply add a rewrite condition to *not rewrite if the file exists* like:

```
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

#### Edit

Just for completeness... The reason why

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\_,]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

works and

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

doesn't is because `.*` includes the characters `?` and `=` where as your pattern doesn't (the `?` and `=` coming from the GET string).

### Question 2

To convert `http://site.com/file.php` to http://site.com/file` you can use the following rewrite rules:

```
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
ReWriteRule ^(.*).php$ $1
```

Comment: The older version of the website had URLs like 'www.example.ch/page1.php', 'www.example.ch/page2.php'. The new Version has URLs like 'www.example.ch/page1'. With your changes above, the dot is now working. But when i call a page like that 'www.example.ch/page1.php' it rewrites the URL to something like http://example.ch/home/httpd/vhosts/example.ch/httpdocs/example.

Comment: What I need to fix with this is simply: In Google there are the old pages like 'www.example.ch/page1.php'. I want them to be redirected to the new page.

Comment: Sorry to go over this again.. But, are you literally just trying to drop the `.php` extension?

Comment: The .php extension is dropped. My Problem is, when i type a page like www.example.ch/page1.php the browser redirects me to the URL example.ch/home/httpd/vhosts/example.ch/httpdocs/example and not to the URL www.example.ch/page1. Where does this path come from?

Comment: Okay, so in that case, what are the rewrite rules you're using to do that? It sounds like you're using `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` in some way?... I assume the `.php` files no longer exist (hence the 404s)? If that's the case I have added a rewrite rule to the answer that will redirect `.php` to non-`.php`